# HTML5 history: how can I see the URL that was popped (ie, the page we were on when we hit the back button)

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I am using the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

I notice that if:

- if I am on a page called /first
- I use pushState to /second
- And then hit the back button

The event handler for window.onpopstate() returns the state for /first, as documented.

In order to transition from /second to /first, **I would like to see the URL that was popped - ie, /second in this case**. What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: have you had a look at libraries like history.js? Or would you rather like to stick with the default implementation?

Comment: @csupnig I'd like to stick to the default implementation if at all possible, however if history.js has a workaround I'd be happy to use it. I could also implement my own workarounds if needed (eg an element attribute hack).

Comment: then i'd suggest you have a look at their implementation. It worked very well when we implemented it on our website (https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Comment: @csupnig I've already looked at history.js but I can't find a mention of it providing the URL the back button was pushed on - only the new head of the queue. Are you saying it provides this? Where in the documentation is it?

Comment: i'd suggest you have a look [https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) here is a simple library that does not require training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of a proper answer, I've implemented the following workaround:

- Using a `data-urlhack` attribute on the `<body>` element when a page is loaded
- In `onpopstate()` handler, checking the value of this attribute so I can transition from this page (where the back button was hit) to the page the back button has sent us to.

Also ensure that pages loaded in `onpopstate()` don't try and push use `pushState()` themselves.

Comment: Thanks for this, resolved an issue I was having where I used `pushState()` in a function that loaded content and it caused navigation and content loading not to work.  I removed it from the function and added it to the on click event and then everything worked.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142705/window-onpopstate-only-effecting-page-range-of-one